# Connecting to an ASP.NET MVC project always requires a DB connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm facing a slight problem. I created a solution and put several projects in it (project ASP.NET MVC, database, and class library).

When I want to start my ASP project, it keeps asking me to connect to the DB:

[The issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maYqX.png)

I have to right-click on the project -> debug and launch a new instance.

Is someone could tell me what I should do or give me a lead? Thank you very much

I tried to change some options in my Visual Studio configuration and change some options in my solution like the start up project ...

Comment: Nuke your `.csproj.user` files and `obj` directories. Also, temporarily _unload_ any SSDT projects in your SLN (MS doesn't realise just how badly SSDT is an embarassment to VS now...)

Comment: What do you mean ? Delete .csproj.user and obj ? This is what i did but still the same :/

Comment: Ok it solved now. The issue was caused by a dependency that was called before my ASP MVC, and it hasked to connect to the database.